# Not able to connect cassandra port 9042 from other machines.

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cassandra

```
sudo docker run --name dc101 -P -d -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME="Cluster1" -e
CASSANDRA_DC="datacenter1" -e CASSANDRA_RACK="rc1" -e
CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH="GossipingPropertyFileSnitch" -e 
CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS="<IPOfUbuntu>" -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS="
<IPOfUbuntu>" -p 9042:9042 cassandra:latest
```

I'm using docker on ubuntu. And trying to create a cassandra node. The above command runs successfully and creates a node. But not able to connect from other systems. I'm able to connect from the same machine. If I telnet to 9042, it is not connecting.

Thanks!

Below is the error log ----

```
INFO  04:00:18 Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-tcnative=netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork19.fe4816e, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-native-epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86]
INFO  04:00:18 Starting listening for CQL clients on /10.24.112.136:9042 (unencrypted)...
    Exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException) encountered during startup: Failed to bind port 9042 on 10.24.112.136.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to bind port 9042 on 10.24.112.136.
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.start(Server.java:164)
        at java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4767)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.NativeTransportService.start(NativeTransportService.java:128)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.startNativeTransport(CassandraDaemon.java:649)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:511)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:616)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730)
ERROR 04:00:18 Exception encountered during startup
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to bind port 9042 on 10.24.112.136.
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.start(Server.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4767) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.NativeTransportService.start(NativeTransportService.java:128) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.startNativeTransport(CassandraDaemon.java:649) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:511) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:616) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
INFO  04:00:18 Announcing shutdown
```

Comment: docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:30:42 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is wrong "The above command runs successfully and creates a node". It doesn't work according to your log

```
ERROR 04:00:18 Exception encountered during startup
INFO  04:00:18 Announcing shutdown
```

I think it's because `rpc_address` should map to the private IP of the docker container, not of the host. Better to leave it to default value

```
sudo docker run --name dc101 -P -d -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME="Cluster1" -e
CASSANDRA_DC="datacenter1" -e CASSANDRA_RACK="rc1" -e
CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH="GossipingPropertyFileSnitch" -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS="
<IPOfUbuntu>" -p 9042:9042 cassandra:latest
```

Comment: After specifying the -e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true while creating the node , it allowed to connect from external machines